# What is the random process underlying this figure

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have the following random process and I would like to know what could be its underlying stochastic process:

[image]

The closest I can get is by simulating the following:

$
dX_t=\displaystyle\frac{dP_t}{k*Sin(t)}
$

where $P_t$ is a Poisson process.

In Mathematica, the simulated random process is:

```
RandomInteger[PoissonDistribution[1], 1000]/10*
  Abs[Table[Sin[x], {x, 1, 1000}]];
```

This gives the following figure:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: a [google reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=simg:CAESkgEajwELEKjU2AQaBAgDCAoMCxCwjKcIGjwKOggCEhSDC54O9Av4C_1AV6hX5C9ALjQ7TDBogQljBkfYkULPifpvIA9DApK27tuOCQ1dIzPecNJdsbZkMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgQiHdjrDAsQne3BCRohCgwKCmVhcnRocXVha2UKBgoEZm9udAoJCgdkaWFncmFtDA&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4BQ0VJj6LurhsATGmYKABw&ved=0CB4Qsw4&biw=942&bih=917) was not very successful :/